# pnp schema template issue - how to inlcude "new and existing guests" option in the schema

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp, office-dev-pnp, pnp-provision

I am not finding the right XML schema to include it in my PNP provisioning template.

How can I include settings called "**New and existing guests**" for external sharing while provisioning a site using pnp provisioning template?

I am not sure where to add exactly here? I also heard that we can include documents in PNP provisioning template, but I am getting error as an invalid template if I include that.

```
<pnp:Provisioning xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2020/02/ProvisioningSchema">
  <pnp:Preferences Generator="OfficeDevPnP.Core, Version=3.18.2002.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5e633289e95c321a" />
  <pnp:Templates ID="CONTAINER-TEMPLATE-1AFCA687C58D4033A2FEC5FDA9F29256">
    <pnp:ProvisioningTemplate ID="TEMPLATE-1AFCA687C58D4033A2FEC5FDA9F29256" Version="1" BaseSiteTemplate="GROUP#0" Scope="RootSite">
      <pnp:WebSettings RequestAccessEmail="" NoCrawl="false" WelcomePage="SitePages/Home.aspx" SiteLogo="{site}/_api/GroupService/GetGroupImage?id='303de100-57ea-4199-b48f-34ddb222df78'&amp;hash=637170283721262427" AlternateCSS="" MasterPageUrl="{masterpagecatalog}/seattle.master" CustomMasterPageUrl="{masterpagecatalog}/seattle.master" HubSiteUrl="https://m365x539190.sharepoint.com/sites/ourclients" CommentsOnSitePagesDisabled="false" QuickLaunchEnabled="true" MembersCanShare="true" SearchScope="DefaultScope" SearchBoxInNavBar="Inherit" />
      <pnp:SiteSettings AllowDesigner="true" AllowCreateDeclarativeWorkflow="true" AllowSaveDeclarativeWorkflowAsTemplate="true" AllowSavePublishDeclarativeWorkflow="true" SearchBoxInNavBar="Inherit" SearchCenterUrl="" />
      <pnp:RegionalSettings AdjustHijriDays="0" AlternateCalendarType="None" CalendarType="Gregorian" Collation="25" FirstDayOfWeek="Sunday" FirstWeekOfYear="0" LocaleId="1033" ShowWeeks="false" Time24="false" TimeZone="13" WorkDayEndHour="5:00PM" WorkDays="62" WorkDayStartHour="8:00AM" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this at a site level currently (it's not included in the current [schema](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/blob/master/ProvisioningSchema-2020-02.md))

I currently set the value in my PS script before I call the Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate 
e.g.

```
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminSiteUrl -Credential $creds
Set-SPOSite -Identity $siteUrl -SharingCapability Disabled
Get-SPOSite -Identity $siteUrl | select Url, SharingCapability
```

Where the possible values for SharingCapability are:

Disabled - don't allow sharing outside your organization,

ExistingExternalUserSharingOnly - Allow sharing only with the external users that already exist in your organization's directory,

ExternalUserSharingOnly - allow external users who accept sharing invitations and sign in as authenticated users, or

ExternalUserAndGuestSharing - allow sharing with all external users, and by using anonymous access links.

Regards,

James